# Finding duplicate values in one dimension of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I have been searching the archives for the better part of a full day and have not been able to find an answer to my question. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

**THE PROBLEM**

Without being able to identify teams that are tied (duplicate win percentage) and logic to break those ties (outside scope of this question), I can't test head to head results and ultimately rank the teams correctly.

**THE QUESTION**

How do I:

1. Identify which teams have the same win percentage (the number of total games played could differ for some teams)
2. Count the number of teams that are tied.

**EXAMPLE MULTIDIMENSIONAL ARRAY**

I have a multidimensional array that stores arrays containing a team number, wins, losses, point differential, and win percentage.

Example:

```
$team_array = array(
array(68, 6, 0, 10, 1.000),
array(65, 6, 0, 8, 1.000),
array(62, 6, 0, 4, 1.000),
array(54, 3, 3, 3, .500),
array(55, 3, 3, -5, .500),
array(59, 0, 6, -16, .000)
);
```

I need help finding duplicate values in only 1 dimension of the multidimensional array (win percentage or $team_array[$x][4]. I do not know if it is better to try to find duplicate values or to eliminate unique values.

If anyone has any thoughts or suggestions, I would GREATLY appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: I know it's not an answer to your question but, have you considered using OOP rather than arrays? Using OOP will simplify the problem in my opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** previous code didn't work.

```
// $seenDuplicate[ Percentage ][] = indexes which have this percentage.
foreach(team_array as $ind => $team){
    $trackPercentages[$team[4]][] = $ind;
}
// then you can count the number of each array in $trackPercentages
```

**Reply to first comment:** 
it's returning 3 because it contains all percentages regardless of duplication. The first is 1.000, second is .5000 and 3rd is .0000

```
foreach($trackPercentages as $perc => $list){
        $echo "Teams with " . $perc . "% wins.<br>";
        foreach($list as $team){
            echo $team."<br>";
        }
        echo "<br>";
}
```

if you only want to show duplicates, then right after first foreach loop, check:

```
if(count($list)>1)
```

And I believe ksort can be used to sort an array based on index.

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab at a solution. I ran your code above with the addition of:
$cnt = count($trackPercentages);
echo "cnt - $cnt<br>";

Unfortunately, this returns "3". This would coordinate to having 3 values of "1.000" but it doesn't account for the 2 other duplicate values of. ".500". For any solution I would need the team_id associated with the duplicate win percentages. I am thinking it might make sense to order the list of arrays by win_percentage then walk the outer array to compare values. Something like:
 if($tm_array[$row][4] == $tm_array[$row+1][4])
 {
  $dup++;
 }

Comment: Again... thanks for the help! If you have any other thoughts or suggestions, they are definitely welcome!